# Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation in libchilkat?

Tags: c++, valgrind, chilkat, chilkat-email

I run **sudo valgrind --leak-check=full -v --track-origins=yes ./myprogram**
The result is:

```
    ==31734== 1 errors in context 7 of 7:
==31734== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==31734==    at 0x61CCCC: TlsProtocol::sendRecord(unsigned char const*, unsigned int, int, int, int, TlsEndpoint&, unsigned int, SocketParams&, LogBase&) (in /home/me/src/myprogram)
==31734==    by 0x61D32E: TlsProtocol::sendHandshakeMessages(DataBuffer&, int, int, TlsEndpoint&, unsigned int, SocketParams&, LogBase&) (in /home/me/src/myprogram)
==31734==    by 0x620B1C: TlsProtocol::sendClientHello(TlsEndpoint&, unsigned int, SocketParams&, LogBase&) (in /home/me/src/myprogram)
==31734==    by 0x6265E7: TlsProtocol::clientHandshake2(TlsEndpoint&, unsigned int, SocketParams&, LogBase&) (in /home/me/src/myprogram)
==31734==    by 0x627789: TlsProtocol::clientHandshake(char const*, int, TlsEndpoint&, unsigned int, SocketParams&, SharedCertChain*, LogBase&) (in /home/me/src/myprogram)
==31734==    by 0x616855: SChannelChilkat::connectImplicitSsl(char const*, int, bool, int, unsigned int, unsigned int, SystemCerts&, SocketParams&, LogBase&, bool&, SharedCertChain*) (in /home/me/src/myprogram)
==31734==    by 0x56DDEB: Socket2::connect2(char const*, int, bool, bool, int, SystemCerts&, unsigned int, unsigned int, SocketParams&, LogBase&, bool&, int&, SharedCertChain*) (in /home/me/src/myprogram)
==31734==    by 0x56E24F: Socket2::socket2Connect(char const*, int, bool, bool, int, SystemCerts&, unsigned int, unsigned int, SocketParams&, LogBase&, bool&, int&, SharedCertChain*, ClsSocksClient&, ClsHttpProxyClient*) (in /home/me/src/myprogram)
==31734==    by 0x514FD9: Imap::connectToImapServer(char const*, int, StringBuffer&, SharedCertChain*, SystemCerts&, ClsSocksClient&, ClsHttpProxyClient*, LogBase&, ProgressMonitor*) (in /home/me/src/myprogram)
==31734==    by 0x48BB69: ClsImap::Connect(XString&, ProgressEvent*) (in /home/me/src/myprogram)
==31734==    by 0x454A5D: CkImap::Connect(char const*) (in /home/me/src/myprogram)
==31734==    by 0x422C2E: EmailSensorAlertConnection::Connect(char const*, int, bool, char const*, char const*) (emailconnection.cpp:150)
==31734==  Uninitialised value was created by a heap allocation
==31734==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==31734==    by 0x47F219: ClsImap::createNewCls() (in /home/me/src/myprogram)
==31734==    by 0x4567EA: CkImap::CkImap() (in /home/me/src/myprogram)
==31734==    by 0x422A13: EmailConnection::EmailConnection(std::string) (emailconnection.cpp:110)
==31734==    by 0x41D364: IMAPConnectionFactory::getIMAPConnection() (imapconnectionfactory.cpp:46)
==31734==    by 0x431362: main (myprogram.cpp:348)
==31734== 
==31734== ERROR SUMMARY: 7 errors from 7 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Part of myprogram.cpp is:

```
bool connectRes = m_imap.Connect( server );//line 348
```

I try to find the uninitialized variable. It seems that it is in:**ClsImap::createNewCls()**. I used grep to search this function. This function is in **libchilkat-e/lib/libchilkat-9.5.0.a**. How to fix this problem? It seems that the problem is in the lib. So I can do nothing? Am I right?

Comment: If the problem is in the library then you don't really have any option but to (a) live with it, (b) not use that library, (c) rebuild the library from source and fix bugs in it

Comment: I spent some time searching the source code of chilkat on Internet, but found nothing.

Comment: This should be fixed in Chilkat v9.5.0.52, due out soon.  Chilkat is extensively testing with valgrind prior to this release..